# Excel VBA Updating multiple rows based on criteria with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010 and VBA
I have 2 columns in excel (call them A + B) – A has a list of names, B will contain;

Blank which means Unsorted
"x"         = Done
"o"         = Open

For the purposes of the question I will call the A column 'Status' and the B column 'Label'. The Label column will contain multiple assorted entries – so maybe something like, Peter, Paul, Simon, Peter, Peter, Simon, Paul, David Etc.

If an entry is "o" I want to fill all the Status cells before the "o" (behind, closer to Row 1) where the Label matches that in the cell next to the "o" Status cell, with an "x".

So in words, if a Status cell, say A25, contains "o" and B25 contains "Paul" I want to fill all Status cells A1 – A24, where B1 – B24 contain "Paul" with an "x".

So, to be clear. I can do this already by looping the A column in reverse, finding a "o" and then continue looping backwards filling in the required entries as I go. That works.

What I am wondering is if there is a better (more cunning) way to change all the required entries in one go. Is that a good idea ?

Whatever the method I will turn this into a function so I can call it with a Label so it can operate on 1 Label at a time.

Any input would be most welcome.

I have simplified and changed my actual process to better suit asking the question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can set the value for an entire range at once, yes.  Something like this: sheets("Sheet1").range(sheets("Sheet1").cells(1,1), sheets("Sheet1").cells(10,1)).value = "x"  OR  sheets("Sheet1").range("B1:B10").value = "o"

Comment: Couldn't say if this would be any faster or better, but another approach: Get an array of the names. For each name in the array, filter column A to match the name, and column B equal to "o". Find the last row where the status = x, and hide all rows after that. Then set column B visible cells to equal "x".

Comment: Chris and Kevin, thank you both for that info. Chris I will give that a try first, thanks. Kevin, I am using an array to do other stuff so I will also look into your suggestion. Thanks very much to both of you for taking the time to read and answer my query. Regards

Comment: Hi Kevin, after looking at the code you posted I see that it just does the setting of a value - I really need to update the value of multiple cells, but only those that are connected to a certain Label in Col B. Thanks very much for posting though, I appreciate all the help.

Comment: If you really want someone to deal with your question, the least you need is: your own code that you want to make faster and some data that can be copied or a photo of the sheet with 10-20 lines as long as it's easy to type of the data. All your references and explanations appear in the posted data, so that you become immediately understandable.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

- Filter the data on the Names (Column A = name), and Unsorted (Column B = "o")
- Change the visible cells Unsorted (Column B) to 'x' except the last row